# How to identify colors in a string with nltk in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors, nltk

The question really speaks for itself, but my problem is I want to be able to identify colors in a string with nltk and all I can find is how to classify parts of speech. I know I could just make a list of all the colors I want to support but since I want to support all the colors available in css this would be quite a long list (some of them get strange, like teal and aquamarine). If there is a simpler way to do this than writing them all out it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit:**

It seems that I forgot to mention when I first asked my question that I required The color names spaced out like in natural language instead of run together due to it's use in speech recognition. Therefore, I have selected "Tadhg McDonald-Jensen"'s answer as the best because it answers my original question quite well. However I have also posted my own answer which supplies color names with spaces. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [the `webcolors` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/webcolors/1.3) to get all css color names that it recognizes, just check for membership of `webcolors.CSS3_NAMES_TO_HEX`:

```
>>> import webcolors
>>> "green" in webcolors.CSS3_NAMES_TO_HEX
True
>>> "deepskyblue" in webcolors.CSS3_NAMES_TO_HEX
True
>>> "aquamarine" in webcolors.CSS3_NAMES_TO_HEX
True
>>> len(webcolors.CSS3_NAMES_TO_HEX)
147
```

This means that `webcolors.CSS3_NAMES_TO_HEX.keys()` will give you a list in python2 or dictkeys set in python3 of all css3 color names.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution (for me anyway):**

> **Note:** If you simply need the colors without spaces ('deepskyblue' instead of 'deep sky blue') any of the previous answers will work.
>   However, since I'm using this in combination with speech recognition I
>   need the colors seperated by spaces as in natural language which can
>   be achieved using the following code (in python 3) which I view as more complete:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getColors():
    html = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_names.asp').read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    children = [item.findChildren() for item in soup.find_all('tr')]
    colors = [''.join( ' '+x if 'A' <= x <= 'Z' else x for x in item[0].text.replace(u'\xa0', '')).strip().lower() for item in children]
    return colors[1:]
```

Then if you run

```
print(getColors())
```

You get:

```
 ['alice blue', 'antique white', 'aqua', 'aquamarine', 'azure', 'beige', 'bisque', 'black', 'blanched almond', 'blue', 'blue violet', 'brown', 'burly wood', 'cadet blue', 'chartreuse', 'chocolate', 'coral', 'cornflower blue', 'cornsilk', 'crimson', 'cyan', 'dark blue', 'dark cyan', 'dark golden rod', 'dark gray', 'dark grey', 'dark green', 'dark khaki', 'dark magenta', 'dark olive green', 'dark orange', 'dark orchid', 'dark red', 'dark salmon', 'dark sea green', 'dark slate blue', 'dark slate gray', 'dark slate grey', 'dark turquoise', 'dark violet', 'deep pink', 'deep sky blue', 'dim gray', 'dim grey', 'dodger blue', 'fire brick', 'floral white', 'forest green', 'fuchsia', 'gainsboro', 'ghost white', 'gold', 'golden rod', 'gray', 'grey', 'green', 'green yellow', 'honey dew', 'hot pink', 'indian red', 'indigo', 'ivory', 'khaki', 'lavender', 'lavender blush', 'lawn green', 'lemon chiffon', 'light blue', 'light coral', 'light cyan', 'light golden rod yellow', 'light gray', 'light grey', 'light green', 'light pink', 'light salmon', 'light sea green', 'light sky blue', 'light slate gray', 'light slate grey', 'light steel blue', 'light yellow', 'lime', 'lime green', 'linen', 'magenta', 'maroon', 'medium aqua marine', 'medium blue', 'medium orchid', 'medium purple', 'medium sea green', 'medium slate blue', 'medium spring green', 'medium turquoise', 'medium violet red', 'midnight blue', 'mint cream', 'misty rose', 'moccasin', 'navajo white', 'navy', 'old lace', 'olive', 'olive drab', 'orange', 'orange red', 'orchid', 'pale golden rod', 'pale green', 'pale turquoise', 'pale violet red', 'papaya whip', 'peach puff', 'peru', 'pink', 'plum', 'powder blue', 'purple', 'rebecca purple', 'red', 'rosy brown', 'royal blue', 'saddle brown', 'salmon', 'sandy brown', 'sea green', 'sea shell', 'sienna', 'silver', 'sky blue', 'slate blue', 'slate gray', 'slate grey', 'snow', 'spring green', 'steel blue', 'tan', 'teal', 'thistle', 'tomato', 'turquoise', 'violet', 'wheat', 'white', 'white smoke', 'yellow', 'yellow green']
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why did you accept my answer if it isn't the solution you used?  I appreciate the rep but if it didn't do what you want I don't think saying "this is the answer I accept" makes much sense.

Comment: I accepted it because it answered my original question where I left out details like that I wanted to use it with speech recognition. Also along the same lines, because it answers the question most other people who probably just want the colors plain, the way they are in css (without the spaces) want to know. So, mostly because it's more helpful to other people and the ones who are doing something simmilar to me can just look at my post an also because I'm knew here and I wasn't really sure what to do.

Comment: P.S. you've obviously done a lot more on here than I have so if you think I should change it I'd be happy to. Thanks!

Comment: um... no actually the explanation in the edit of the question (that I missed before posting that comment) does an excellent job of explaining it, and thinking of the site in terms of future viewers is exactly what it was designed for so keep up that attitude!  :D

Comment: Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

I would not use nltk but regex.

1. Get a list of all css colors ([here](http://colours.neilorangepeel.com/))
2. extract the color names and build a list (using beautifulsoup)
3. build a regex pattern
4. use this regex pattern to match what you want in your string

This work for me
(you just need to change the 2 last lines and the proxy setup if needed)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

color_url = 'http://colours.neilorangepeel.com/'
proxies = {'http': 'http://proxy.foobar.fr:3128'}#if needed

#GET THE HTML FILE
import urllib.request
authinfo = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()# set up authentication info
proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler(proxies)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support, authinfo,
                                     urllib.request.CacheFTPHandler)# build a new opener that adds authentication and caching FTP handlers
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)# install the opener
colorfile = urllib.request.urlopen(color_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(colorfile, 'html.parser')

#BUILD THE REGEX PATERN
colors = soup.find_all('h1')
colorsnames = [color.string for color in colors]
colorspattern = '|'.join(colorsnames)
colorregex = re.compile(colorspattern)

#MATCH WHAT YOU NEED
if colorregex.search(yourstring):
    do what you want
```